# Can I (should I) do anything about these open PVC exhaust pipes in regards to rain or pests

Tags: water, exhaust-fan

I moved into my current home recently and noticed these exhaust pipes are open.
Do I have to worry about rodents or insects getting in?

Can I improvise a makeshift screen with some additional PVC pipe or would that be out of code?

Additionally, should I be concerned about rain water on the center exhaust? It may be very little, but I imagine some getting in isn't great?

I was thinking of (again) improving a rain cover to prevent any water from dripping in.

[image]

Comment: Tell us what those pipes are, exactly. Good (and safe) answers depend on it. I assume (left to right) furnace intake, furnace exhaust, water heater exhaust, but we need to know. A little tapping or speaking with a partner on the inside should make it fairly clear. You can also wait for those things to run and check for pressure on the pipe terminations.

Comment: Fair question, I'll look into it. 
I'm in Ontario, Canada in case anyone is familiar with local codes applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Your setup looks completely standard to me. In my region we have converted most HVAC systems and water heaters to high efficiency units. They vent nearly room-temperature gas via PVC in most cases. The inlets and outlets are arranged to prevent recirculation of exhaust gases into your home, and the outlets have mechanisms inside to deal with drainage from condensation and a bit of rain.

Regarding rodents... it's possible. About once a year I get mice in my suburban home, and I suspect the HVAC plumbing as an ingress point. However, it can be dangerous to apply mesh. Accumulation of dust, lint, insect nests, natural material, or whatever can obstruct intake and exhaust flow, potentially causing health and safety issues. I'd avoid doing so.

My $.03? **Don't change anything unless there's an actual problem.** If you must, consult an HVAC specialist for the right way to deal with the specific issue. Mesh covers may be available that provide a large surface area unlikely to clog, for example.

Answer (score 1):

If rats got in, where would they get to?

Well, in response to the comments, all the high efficiency furnaces in two countries that I have lived in have to have metal for the exhaust tubes. And they can have grilles fitted, these are usually cubes of metal mesh with a 1cm square mesh and the cube is 30cm on a side, this is a solution allowed in both countries to make sure no birds can get in and nobody can get their fingers in or even kids poking things into the tubes.

Comment: It may be illegal or unwise to put mesh over combustion exhaust vents. Around here it's not done for safety reasons.

Comment: Also, adding another elbow to the exhaust pipe may put it too close to the intake (or vice versa). You don't want your equipment recirculating exhaust. Also, exhaust pipes already have a lot of condensation in them and the means for handling that. There's no need to extend.

Comment: @isherwood combustion vents in a material that is combustible? usually combustion vents are made of metal,

Comment: Nope. Nearly every high efficiency furnace in my northern region exhausts through PVC. So do water heaters.

Comment: Those are normal for high efficiency burners, the exhaust gas is basically nearly cold. Any rain that gets into the exhaust will just be collected by the condensate drain. Seems like a standard setup to me.

Comment: I like 1cm mesh better than the 3mm you had earlier. That's much less likely to clog and cause safety issues.

Comment: @isherwood If I remember I will take a picture of my sister's version but not travelling much at the moment. But it may not be code compliant in other places - seems a sensible way though.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased a roll of 1/4" square mesh from the hardware store, which usually comes in 3'x5' rolls. I cut a 3"x3" piece out for each 2" vent pipe and used 3/16" (4) self-tapping screws on each side (12,3,6,9 oclock) of the vent pipe to secure it in place.

I have experienced the same smell. There is a sewage smell in the area where the mice are located between the floor joists, which is inaccessible unless I cut out sheetrock, and the same smell is fifteen feet away in the bathroom from the toilet. I have no idea how they're getting in, as all areas of the house are secure. The only other place would be the roof plumbing vent, which has no screen.

The room where the smell is has no plumbing other than a water line running between the joists. There is no sewer pipe running near it. However, the air duct does run over the bathroom and into the room. The smell is only present around the area where the duct blows air. Otherwise, the room smells fine. The utility room does not smell, and the bathroom is next to it. The smell comes and goes, and you can tell something is present when it comes. My face gets flush, and my cheeks burn.

Comment: Mice can get through amazingly tiny openings, and their nests are full of mouse poop pellets and mouse urine, apparently the smell makes them feel at home. Perhaps that smell is what you have wafting in; I think there's probably ammonia as part of it.

Comment: They can't get through 1/4," and It is mice. I have a camera on the rim joists but cannot locate the nesting area since I cannot fish the camera in between joists unless I start drilling holes or cutting sheetrock.  Yes, ammonia is part of it. The smell did change after shoving throw packs of mousex covered in peanut butter on the rim joist, and I have seen one of the mice eating away at it, but haven't noticed much over the past two weeks. The smell previously was horrid, now it's more subtle.